# How can I create a shared folder using command line?

Tags: command-line, shared-folders

1. On a stand-alone PC, using the Live CD of Ubuntu, how can I create a shared folder using command line?
2. After this, how can shared folder be shared with a group utilizing command line?
3. Lastly, how can I change the permission of shared folder only for the group as read write and execute, and none others, except for the root as the owner?

Comment: what specifically do you mean by shared folder?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a directory is done with the `mkdir foo` command.
you could make a new group of users with the `addgroup bar` command and add root to the new group.
Then you change the owner of the new directory by `chown root:bar foo`.
Finally set the permissions: `chmod 770 foo`